# Swift: Navigation Bar ist hiding although I call the required code?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have two VCs with the same navigation Controller and on my first VC the navigation Bar should be hidden and the second one large. The two VC are connected via a push segue. But if I click on the back button which appears after a push segue the navigation Bar appears again although when the VC first appears there is no Navigation Bar.
My code on the first VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController!.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method viewDidLoad() is only called once so just but the line of code in the viewWillAppear method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationController!.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: that helped me a lot

Comment: Up voted because you answered first. But don't forget to include "safety" or "meaningful" or readable coding practices... If you intend to hide the bar in *some* VCs but not in *others*, there's nothing wrong with including your intent *explicitly* in *every* VC.

Answer (score 1):

You have to hide the navigation bar inside your viewWillAppear function and have to unhide it inside your viewWillDisappear function of your first VC, so that it don't get hidden for all the VCs. Just use the following code, it'll work:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```